# Bloquear meio de contato com PHP

Tags: php

Estou a desenvolver um sistema onde preciso não permitir formas de contato como email, skype, facebook e telefone. Queria usar `str_replace()` só que eu iria ter que fazer uma lista gigante com algumas palavras que contém nesses itens e substituir por nada `''` . Teria algum plugin ou um open-source que já faz esse serviço? Ou até mesmo um código de base?

Comment: Pode ser até que tenha, mas pra bloquear usuário de skype acredito que não. Talvez devesse ter um moderador que fique monitorando isso.

Comment: Defina "não permitir formas de contato".

Comment: @Renan, o que ele quer dizer é não permitir dados de contato, descritos ali na pergunta `email, skype, facebook e telefone`

Comment: Não permitir como? O usuário não pode escrever em uma caixa de texto? Não pode ter no perfil? Não pode mencionar em comentário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os usuários vão arrumar uma forma de passar informação pessoal.

Se não pode email: `papa@charlie.com`, alguem vai mudar até sua regra falhar: `papa arroba charlie ponto com, papa(a)charlie dot com`... infinitas possibilidades.

---

Recomendo um algorítimo que procure certas palavras, mas não impede o cadastro, apenas crie um alerta de que há uma possível informação de contato para você fazer análise.

1. Uma ER pode encontrar email ou números de telefone, Skype ou perfil do FB, Twitter, ou qualquer outro site de rede social.
2. Pode criar um array de `(0, 1, 2, ... 9)` e um array de `(zero, um, dois, ... nove)` e percorrer o texto para encontrar possíveis combinações entre números e texto.

Fiz um exemplo simples, pode ver no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/KYn1gj).

---

```
function validate( $string )
{
    // caracteres que serão encontrados em sequencia
    $block[]   = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
    $block[]   = array('um','dois','tres','quatro','cinco','seis','sete','oito','nove','zero');
    $block     = array_merge( $block[0] , $block[1] );

    // agrupa a sequencia encontrada
    $sequencia = array();
    $string    = explode( ' ' , $string );

    // procura a sequencia de 3 caracteres quee stiverem no `array block`
    // palavra anterior + palavra atual + palavra seguinte formando uma sequencia de 3 caracteres
    foreach( $string as $i => $palavra )
    {
        $match = array();

        if( isset( $string[$i-1] ) )
        $match[] = $string[$i-1];

        $match[] = $string[$i];

        if( isset( $string[$i+1] ) )
        $match[] = $string[$i+1];


        $possivel = array_intersect( $match , $block );
        if( count( $possivel ) === 3 )
        $sequencia[] = $possivel;
    }

    return $sequencia;
}
```

nesse exemplo abaixo o output será um array multidimensional com `array('1' , 'dois' , '3' )` e `array('quatro' , 'cinco' , 'zero' )`

```
$sequencia = validate( "meu 1 dois 3 telefone ligue quatro cinco zero" );

if( count( $sequencia ) > 0 )
{
    echo printr( 'possível sequência: ' );
    echo printr( $sequencia );
}
else
{
    echo printr( 'parece ok.' );
}
```

---

Note que a sequência vai levar em conta a grafia. Você pode incrementar uma ER junto para que a ortografia não seja impedimento. É simples e server como base.

Comment: Apesar do seu exemplo Não ser o 100% o que eu preciso, mas me serviu como base, como você mesmo disse, o usuário tentará burlar de todas as formas o jeito de colocar email ou alguma informação de contato. Eu acho que o mais apropriado é colocar um moderador para ver as mensagens, igual ao Workana.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli Sim, vão tentar entre caracteres especiais, entre letras, em inglês... São muitas possibilidades - a regra seria imensa. Por isso quando houver suspeita, crie um alerta, ou moderação como você citou.